# Rectangle Angle Property

Tags: c#, wpf, angle

Is it possible to set the rectangle angle property in C#?

I tried this:

```
Rectangle r = new Rectangle();
r.Width = 5;
r.Height = 130;
r.Fill = Brushes.Black;
r.RotateTransform.AngleProperty = 30; // Here is the problem
canvas1.Children.Add(r);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to do this is to apply a [RotateTransformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750596.aspx#exampleRotateAnElement45degSection) to the `RenderTransform` property of the object:

```
r.RenderTransform = new RotateTransform(30);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
RotateTransform rt1 = new RotateTransform();
rt1.Angle =30;
r.RenderTransform= rt1;
```

OR

```
r.RenderTransform= new RotateTransform(30);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to set the backing field of a dependency property, which is readonly and not meant to be used that way.

Use the correct property instead:

```
r.RenderTransform.Angle = 30;
```

Also, i would guess that a new Rectangle doesn't by default have a RotateTransform, so you probably need to create a new instance of that, too:

```
r.RenderTransform= new RotateTransform();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply a skew transform for change angles **in** Rectangle, look at this: [How to: Skew an Element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms746708.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Yesterday I solved the same problem. This is what I use in **WinForms**:

```
        GraphicsState graphicsState = graphics.Save();
        graphics.TranslateTransform(this.Anchor.Position.X, this.Anchor.Position.Y);
        graphics.RotateTransform(this.Anchor.Rotation);
        graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(this.Anchor.Color), this.Anchor.GetRelativeBoundingRectangle());
        graphics.Restore(graphicsState);
```

Anchor is a class I have created. It derives from my own rectangle

```
internal class Rectangle
{
    public PointF Position { get; set; }

    public Color Color { get; set; }

    public SizeF Size { get; set; }

    public float Rotation { get; set; }

    public RectangleF GetRelativeBoundingRectangle()
    {            
        return new RectangleF(
            new PointF(-this.Size.Width / 2.0f, -this.Size.Height / 2.0f),
            this.Size);
    }
}
```

The position of the rectangle is the middle (centre) point of the rectangle, not uppper left corner.

So to get back to the first code part:

```
GraphicsState graphicsState = graphics.Save();
```

I save the state of my graphics device, so I can do whatever I want and then return to the original view. Then I translate the position system to the centre of the rectangle and perform the rotation

```
graphics.TranslateTransform(this.Anchor.Position.X, this.Anchor.Position.Y);
graphics.RotateTransform(this.Anchor.Rotation);
```

Then, I draw the rectangle. This part will be obviously different, based on how you want to draw the rectangle. You would propbably use either FillRectangle (as I do) or DrawRectangle which draws only the borders:

```
graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(this.Anchor.Color), this.Anchor.GetRelativeBoundingRectangle());
```

Finally I restore the original state of the graphic device, which cancels the translation and rotation I used only for drawing the rotated rectangle

```
graphics.Restore(graphicsState);
```